# Toggle switch a particular button in a row in nested records

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some nested records displayed with php and on each record contains a submit button. when a user click on a particular record its able to send to the database correctly. but the problem the button is supposed to be toggled and when you submit a particular record instead of toggling only that particular button, all the buttons on each record toggles.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" class="input_form">
  <label for="item"></label>
  <input type="text" name="item" id="item" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="input1" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="" class="input_form">
  <label for="item"></label>
  <input type="text" name="item" id="item" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="input1" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="" class="input_form">
  <label for="item"></label>
  <input type="text" name="item" id="item" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="input1" />
</form>
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".input_form").on('submit', function(event) {
    $('.input1,.input2').toggleClass('input2', 'input');
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('.input2').hasClass('inpu2')) {
      data = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/myapp/scripts/inputs.php",
        data: data
      }).success(function() {});
    } else {
      if ($('.input').hasClass('input')) {
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/myapp/scripts/input_delete.php",
          data: data
        }).success(function() {});
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show us your html code (that's generated). And what do you mean by "toogled" - only swotch classes input2 and input?

Comment: `$('.input').hasClass('input')`. Serious?

Comment: what i mean is when i submit a particular row instead of that button changing class, all the buttons class changes

Comment: We need the HTML to help you. There are too many differents class name to understand (you have input1 and input2, which toggle with input2 and input. And there is class inpu2)

Comment: So if I understand well => `inpu2` is typo mistake and class `input` doesn't exist (or should be `input1`)?

Comment: You are using the same class `input1` for all the submit buttons and this code `$('.input1,.input2').toggleClass('input2', 'input');` toggles the classes of all those buttons. And you are using same ids for all your fields which is not valid. So please correct your code first.

Comment: Do you want the submitted form's button to be changed to something else? Like a delete button? And when clicked on that button the request should go to `http://localhost/myapp/scripts/input_delete.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of typo errors in your code..

1) `$('.input1,.input2').toggleClass('input2', 'input');` This will select all the buttons with the class `.input1` and `.input2` and toggle it. What you want is to select specific buttons only. So navigate from the `form`

```
$(this).find('.input,.input2').toggleClass('input2', 'input'); 
// note input1 is changed to input as I dont see input1
// anywhere else, hence assuming to be a typo
```

Here `$(this)` will point to the `form` that triggered the `submit` event.

2) other issue is

```
if ($('.input2').hasClass('inpu2')) {
```

and

```
if ($('.input').hasClass('input')) {
```

Here you are trying to select elements with class `.input2` and `.input`. YOu are just selecting elements by a particular class and are checking if that element contains that class which is always true and not logical. What you actually want is to **check if your `input` element has those classes**.

So change it to this

```
if ($(this).find('input').hasClass('input2')) {
```

and

```
if ($(this).find('input').hasClass('input')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

```
$('.input1,.input2').toggleClass('input2', 'input');
```

into

```
$('input[type=submit]', this).toggleClass('input2', 'input');
```

(Not sure if the last thing should be input1)